# Saving search history with many checks and validations inside

Tags: java, search

I am absolutely confused by `saveSearchHistory` function. It seems dirty and unobvious.
Should I refactor it, and how?

**SearchHistory.java**

```
public class SearchHistory {
  public SearchHistory(Long userId, Long groupId, String searchString) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.searchString = searchString;
    }
  ...
  //getters + setters
  ...
  public void validate() throws InvalidParameterException{
    if (searchString == null || searchString.length() < MIN_WORD_SIZE) {
      throw new InvalidParameterException("Wrong search word min size: "+searchString);
    }

    if (searchString.length() > MAX_WORD_SIZE) {
        searchString = searchString.substring(0, MAX_WORD_SIZE - 1);
    }
}
}
```

**SearchHistoryController.java**

```
@Repository
public class SearchHistorControllerImpl implements SearchHistoryController {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "userPU")
    private EntityManager userEm;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<SearchHistory> getSearchHistories(Long userId) {
        return emptyIfNull(userEm.createNamedQuery("getSearchHistories")
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .getResultList());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public SearchHistory saveSearchHistory(Long userId, Long groupId, String word) throws InvalidParameterException{
        SearchHistory searchHistory = new SearchHistory(userId, groupId, word);
        searchHistory.validate(); //throws InvalidParameterException

        removeSameWord(userId, groupId, word);
        checkWordsSizeLimit(userId, groupId);

        searchHistory = userEm.merge(searchHistory);
        userEm.flush();
        return searchHistory;
    }

    private void removeSameWord(Long userId, Long groupId, String word) {
        userEm.createNamedQuery("removeSameWord")
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .setParameter("groupId", groupId)
                .setParameter("searchString", word)
                .executeUpdate();
    }

    private void checkWordsSizeLimit(Long userId, Long groupId){
        List<SearchHistory> searchHistoryIds = userEm.createNamedQuery("findOldSearchWordsIds")
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .setParameter("groupId", groupId)
                .setFirstResult(MAX_HISTORY_SIZE - 1)
                .getResultList();

        if (!searchHistoryIds.isEmpty()) {
            userEm.createNamedQuery("removeOldWords")
                    .setParameter("searchHistoryIds", searchHistoryIds)
                    .executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchHistory.html.xml**

```
...
<query name="findOldSearchWordsIds">
    SELECT id
     FROM SearchHistory as searchHistory
     WHERE
        searchHistory.userId = :userId
        AND searchHistory.groupId = :groupId
     ORDER BY searchHistory.searchTime DESC
</query>

<query name="removeOldWords">
    DELETE FROM SearchHistory as searchHistory
    WHERE searchHistory.id in ( :searchHistoryIds )
</query>

<query name="removeSameWord">
    DELETE FROM SearchHistory as searchHistory
    WHERE
        searchHistory.searchString = :searchString
        AND searchHistory.userId = :userId
        AND searchHistory.groupId = :groupId
</query>
...
```

**FullSearch.java**

```
 ...
public void commandExecute() {
    buildSearchResult();

    if (whetherSaveRequestInHistory) {
        final String filteredString = StringUtils.removeEnd(filterString, "*");
        try {
            searchHistoryManager.saveSearchHistory(context.getUserId, groupId, filteredString);
        } catch (InvalidParameterException ipe) {
            log.info("Unable to save Search History to db: "+ ipe.getMessage());
        }
    }
} 

...
```

Answer (score 2):

> It seems dirty and unobvious.

I wouldn't go that far. I think that the code generally looks fine.

**Style**

The indentation and spacing is generally fine, but sometimes it is inconsistent (2 vs 4 spaces, spaces around `+`).

**validate**

I would validate right in the constructor instead of in a public method, because someone might forget to call the method, and then you end up with an invalid object.

And as `validate` has side-effects (it doesn't just check the string, it actually changes it), I would add a JavaDoc comment.

**removeSameWord**

Is this method really needed? Your database schema should be able to use a unique constraint to not allow duplicate rows. Or, since you are using `merge`, you should also be able to just remove it completely, since merge updates existing entries.

**Naming**

- Sometimes, you use `word` or `words` and sometimes `searchString` for what seems to me to be the same thing. This is a bit confusing, you should use variable names consistently.
- the query `removeOldWords` could just be `removeByIds`, because it doesn't care if words are old or new, it just deletes all words with the given ids.
- `checkWordsSizeLimit` doesn't just check, it also deletes, the name should reflect this (maybe something like `enforceWordsSizeLimit`; or split the method up in `getLastIds` and `removeByIds`).
- the query `removeSameWord` could be renamed to `remove` (the query doesn't really care if it's the same word as some other word, it just removes the given entry).
- `removeSameWord` could also be `remove` (the parameters make it clear what will be removed) or `removeExisting`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
How I can use merge in **removeSameWord**, if I create a new searchHistory (thus, I should write select query before)? I also can use index in db because, I should keep in db searrh word with last updated access time.